# Programmatically add Woocommerce product tags

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, tags, product

How can I bulk insert Woocommerce Product Tags?

Comment: `wp_set_post_tags` ??

Answer (score 4):

I have tested different methods and found that this works the best for my case:

```
wp_set_object_terms($productID, array('product_tag1','product_tag2','product_tag3'), 'product_tag');
```